# Python object is nullified after calling

Tags: python, object, null, permutation, python-itertools

If I make any operation on an object, it is nullified after. Why is it so? Looks like list() method is doing it.

```
from itertools import permutations

my_string = 'ada'

result = permutations(my_string)
result2 = permutations(my_string)

print(result)
print('Number of variations is: ', len(list(result)))
print(list(result))


print(' ')

print(result)
print('Number of variations is: ', len(list(result)))
print(list(result))
```

The first three attempts to print() the object are a success.

```
<itertools.permutations object at 0x0000015B4B4555E0>
Number of variations is:  6
[('a', 'd', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'd'), ('d', 'a', 'a'), ('d', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'd'), ('a', 'd', 'a')]
```

The second attempt to print() them gives Null.

```
<itertools.permutations object at 0x0000015B4B4555E0>
Number of variations is:  0
[]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right output. Did you try running it? The program should print an empty list both the times

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate multiple times through the result of itertools.permutations(). From the results you are showing, it looks like you have done:

```
result = permutations(my_string)
len(list(result))
len(list(result))
```

An iterator can be used once and only once.  If you need to iterate through the permutation a second time, either call `permuations()` again, or hold onto `list(result)`.

I noticed that you printed the value of the iterator, and both times is showed the exact same iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains everything! Yes, sorry, I've made a mistake when copying the code.

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) returns an iterator. Iterators can only be looped over once.

After you do `list(result)`, the `result` iterator is exhausted and thus `len(result)` will be 0.

I also assume you made a mistake while copying the output since when you actually run the code, only the first call(`len(list(result))`) gives [the expected output](https://ideone.com/Mslwyr).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains everything! Yes, sorry, I've made a mistake when copying the code.